# Coded UI: Using datasource without login in the website

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I know how to run datasource in coded ui. But my website needs to login in before doing anything on it. And I want to run the test using multiple input data without login to the website each input data. How can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: Search here on Stack Overflow for `[coded-ui-tests] keep browser open`.

Comment: I search for it and found out the way to keep the browser open after finishing the test (set CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false). However, it does not perform the next row in datasource and i don't know why. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Data driving Coded UI tests is normally straightforward. There are no details in your question of what you have tried and what happens. Please write a new question describing in detail the problem you have with data driving and also what you have tried and what happened.

Answer (score 0):

You could do as following (works for me):
- CUIT that starts your browser
- CUIT that navigates to your website
- CUIT for logging in to your website
- all your other Code UI Tests
- CUIT for logging out of your website
- CUIT for closing your browser

Of course you can merge some of the CUIT, but that makes them less reusable.

Comment: Could you please be more specific on how you do that? In my test, I have add 2 methods, one for launch browser, login to website, and one for other code which is using the datasource but it does not work. It is still need to login to the website again before using another row in datasource. Thanks

Comment: I don't use a datasource. I'm getting my data from a database using a ADO.NET Entity Data Model in a Data Access layer. You could make a table with all the data you need to input on your website. If you retrieve that data to a list of objects you could iterate over them in your test.